# skip the loop certain number of times if a condition satisfies in a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a `for` loop in `range(100)`.

Whenever I find a number that does satisfy a condition, it should skip a loop certain number of times

```
for i in range(2,100):
    if i %2 != 0:
        i = i+3
```

Expected results should be:

```
2
3
6
7
10
11
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: what is your condition on which you want to skip?

Comment: `if i %2 != 0:`, i should skip the loop three times

Comment: `1 % 2` is 1... it matches the condition but there is no skip.

Comment: How would you expect this result? After `0` is printed `i` will be `1` so your if will be `True` while `i %2 != 0` is True so `i` will become `i = i+3 =4`

Comment: sorry, lets say the loop starts from 2
`for i in range(2,100)`

Comment: @KostasCharitidis, yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A for-loop does not allow you to skip multiple cycles. You can only use

- `continue` to skip the rest of the current cycle
- `break` to skip all remaining cycles and exit the loop

What you need is a while-loop. Where a for-loop defines a number that is incremented from a starting value up to a limit, a while-loop only needs an exit-condition.

Try this:

```
i = 2
while i < 100:
  if i % 2 == 0:
    i += 4
  else:
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding this is what you want to do. But its not the output you desire. But I guess your expected output is not the output of your logic.

```
i = 2
while i<100:
    print(i)
    if i % 2 != 0:
        i += 3
    else:
        i += 1
```

Outputs:

```
2
3
6
7
10
11
...
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry my problem statement was confusing, How can we get the same in for loop ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 j = 0
 for i in range(j,100):
    if i%2 !=0:
      j = i+3
      continue
    print(j)
```

output:
0
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
.
.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `i = i+3` has no effect in a `for` loop. you may think that `i` becomes `2+3=5` but in the next iteration `i` will be `3`. You need to use a `hile` loop for this. This will do the trick for you:

```
i = 2
while i <= 100:
    print(i)
    i = (i + 3) if i % 2 != 0 else (i + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with a for loop (although I think a while loop is better for this):

```
skipping = 0
for i in range(2, 100):
    if skipping:
        skipping -= 1
        continue
    if i % 2 != 0:
        print(i)
        skipping = 2
    else:
        print(i)
```

Output:

```
2
3
6
7
10
11
...
```